# Prove one argument

Tags: proof-verification, formal-proofs

We all know if there is $$p\Rightarrow q$$

We must prove from $p$ and manipulate it with little algebra until get $q$ right? (In this case, just forget about reductio ad absurdum and contraposition, cz i wanna use classic way)  I mean we go from $p$ to $q$

But what if we meet a different case. When the case is just prove p.

For example:

Prove $(an+b)m\equiv bm\pmod{n}$

There is no information about those variable are. Just assume that they are integers.

So, what i did is:

$$\begin{align} (an+b)m &\equiv bm\pmod{n}\\
&\iff n|[(an+b)m]-bm\\
&\iff n|anm\\
&\iff n|nam \tag {true}
\end{align}
$$

But i don't think that this's correct. Because i go from $p$. But $p$ is not yet proved or unkown.

Please do a correction if there are mistakes..
Thanks.

Comment: You showed $p$ is equivalent to a true statement, therefore $p$ must be..

Comment: “We all know...” - I do not...

Comment: "When the case is just prove $p$..." Well, you have to provide a proof of $p$, i.e. deriving it from axioms or already proven theorems.

Comment: If you prove $p \leftrightarrow q$ and $q$ is an axiom or theorem, then it is a valid proof of $p$.